# Datastax java-driver fetching row key

Tags: cassandra, key, row, cql, datastax-java-driver

I have been stuck while working with java-driver. I execute a CQL query and fetch all rows.

How do I get the key from the `com.datastax.driver.core.Row` object?

Comment: Assuming you included the key column(s) in your select call, you retrieve them just like another column (getInt, getString, etc.)

Comment: "execute a CQL query and fetch all rows" - That's usually not a good idea to do with Cassandra.  I don't see anywhere in the Row or Rowset objects that  returns that type of meta data...probably because it's assumed that if you're working with a ResultSet object in client code, that you've already queried by the key(s).

Answer (score 1):

The same way as any other column, for example `myRow.getString("myKey")`

There are a bunch of helpfull methods in the `Row` class: https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/Row.html